# PHP file_get_contents cookie

Tags: php

Hi all I need to store my cookies on another server.
Let me explain with `file_get_contents` I print the content of this page

```
http://ESEMPIO/#/search?c[q]=$c&MIA_STRINGA[section]=audio
```

But I can not because you must first log in, so my question is
Cookies can store and use the function `file_get_contents`?.
Thanks

Comment: Cookies are stored client-side, not server side. As much as possible, please clarify what you're doing.

Comment: It won't work anyway, because everything after the `#` is for ajax, I presume.

Answer (score 1):

You want your webapplication to logon to another webapplication?

cURL is perfect for that, see 
http://www.copypastecode.com/27076/
for example.

regards,
/t